# Phonegap Built bar code scanner struggles on changed position of the camera

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap app that has been working great, until I got my nexus 5x. Apparently Google put the Camera in upside-down... so scanning the bar code becomes really difficult...

For my bar code scanner in my config file I have:

```
<gap:plugin name=" phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" />
```

I use the below JS code to launch the bar code scanner:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
function (result) {
var barCode = result.text;

//suggest how to continue my code with the bar code that was received. 
}

);
```

Comment: See.. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner